# Xamarin iOS: How to connect a view from a storyboard to a controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I have an storyboard with a ViewController and inside the ViewController I have a UICollectionView with a prototype cell.

I already have an "MyCollectionViewController" (because I try to wrap my CollectionViewController in a ViewController). Now I want to reuse that controller but I can't figure out how to connect the CollectionView from the storyboard with a new CollectionViewController.
Assigning the CollectionView from the CollectionViewController to the Outlet in the ViewController doesn't seem to work.

I know I could make the cell prototype a .xib file and create the CollectionView in code. But my employer prefers having everything in the storyboard for easier maintenance.

EDIT:
The answer from chkn works great.
To connect the parent view controller to the container you can override the PrepareSegue method like this.

```
    public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);
        if (segue.SourceViewController == this) {
            if (segue.DestinationViewController.GetType () == typeof(MyChildViewController)) {
                MyChildViewController childViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as MyChildViewController;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a view from one view controller into an outlet on another view controller.

You can, however, have a single view controller containing the collection view, and then embed that view controller onto other view controllers using container views.

Simply create the view controller hosting the `UICollectionView` (it's easy to just use a `UICollectionViewController`, but it doesn't matter). Then on each view controller you want to embed it in, drag a Container View from the toolbox and remove the default view controller that comes with it. Then, Ctrl+drag from the Container View to the shared `UICollectionView` controller you want to embed.

Your storyboard might look something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

That example is available here:
https://github.com/chkn/StoryboardExamples/tree/master/CollectionViewReuse

Comment: That looks like the right approach for my problem, thank you!
I'll let you now if I can make it work.

Comment: It works perfectly and I can even reuse my previous CollectionViewController.

Comment: Just one thing I don't understand:
How do I get the embedded controller? I need to pass an variable to the embedded view controller before I push the parent view controller to the navigation stack.

Comment: Thats what I did. Added the code in my question of others.